# Do Any Test Case Corpi Exist?

Tags: manual-testing, testcase

I'm interested in using test cases as data for some NLP stuff that I want to do (one of the things I want to do, for instance, is extract verbs and nouns from supplied sentences). To make it easier for me to do this, I've tried to locate a free of charge corpus of test cases, so I don't have to continually search for example test cases online or make my own test cases (in the latter case, this could introduce bias into the results). I would be satisfied with any corpus of test cases, even if they were not all in a consistent format.
Do any such corpi exist?

Comment: "test case corpi" is kind of disturbing for me. We don't think about corpses. If you are looking for a source code for unit tests, most open source projects have them, so you can get tens of thousands samples. See in example debian project. You might want to group your analysis by used test framework. Another families of tests are UI test by Fit, Fitnesse, or Selenium. Also, you might separate them by programming languages used.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest digging around some higher-reputation open source project or other software with public repositories. Unit tests would be incredibly common as well as more integration or gui style tests might be found in some wider-scope projects like Magento's [test directory on github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.2-develop/dev/tests)